# Template10 Resume running services after app suspension

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml, win-universal-app, template10

I am developing a UWP template 10 (Hamburger) app which makes use of the Microsoft Band, I thought I had pretty much finished as I have all my services tied up to the Band (through a class library project) and the values are updating on screen perfectly.
I then started testing app resume and came across a problem.
When I restart an app the user is taken back to the values page but the values no longer update.
Basically the connection to the band seems to still be valid but the readingchanged voids are no longer working.

So I added code in the MainPageViewModel OnNavigatedFromAsync method to stop all of the services no problem.
But then I found that when resuming the OnNavigatedToAsync method does not get fired so I can't work out how to restart all the services.

I also tried adding the overrides for OnResuming and OnSuspendingAsync in app.xaml.cs but then can't work out how to call methods in the MainPageViewModel from there.
Is there a proper way to handle things like this using Template10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using Simulation Dashboard controls in Visual Studio to suspend and then resume your app. Well, then don't use the resume button. It doesn't work as expected. To test resuming of your app, use the suspend button and then open it from the Band's interface (instead of using the resume button). The OnNavigatedToAsync method should then fire just fine.

**Update**:
Based on the discussion following this answer, I am providing an updated answer on the following lines.

Set up a static viewmodel property in the `App` class, like this:

```
public static TypeOfMyViewModel MyViewModel;
```

Then, in the `TypeOfMyViewModel` constructor, add the following line to set value to the property:

```
public TypeOfMyViewModel()
{
    App.MyViewModel = this;
}
```

And, finally, in the `OnResuming` method just call a method from the ViewModel which will resume your services, like this:

```
public override void OnResuming(object s, object e, AppExecutionState previousExecutionState)
{
    MyViewModel.ResumeServices();
}
```

Comment: Ah OK interesting, I have been using the resume option yes. As you say using resume from the Lifecycle events does not call OnNavigatedToAsync. However it still doesn't quite work as expected. If I suspend the app and then re-launch it from the start menu then I can catch OnNavigated to Async and restart everything, my values then start updating again, great :) however If I try and resume by using the task list (long hold on back arrow) the event still does not fire and the services don't start up again..

Comment: Ah, sorry, you are right, it does not fire. However, I think that you should not be stopping your services at all when the app is suspending. According to the [Developer's Guide to Windows 10](https://mva.microsoft.com/en-US/training-courses/a-developers-guide-to-windows-10-12618), episode Application Lifecycle, Windows will do that for you. After you return to the app, your code should be resumed. All async calls started before suspension will then return an error. Please see the video starting at about 12 minute mark for more details.

Comment: Yes I wasn't expecting to have to stop all the services, that's just where I ended up in trying to get everything running again once it resumes. With the band there are not any async calls being made as such I don't think. You fire an async command to start them, for example 'await _bandClient.SensorManager.RRInterval.StartReadingsAsync();' you then just listen for the band raising events '_bandOperator.EventRRIntervalChanged += _bandOperator_EventRRIntervalChanged;' after resuming those events just no longer get raised without calling that first piece of code again.

Comment: I guess the only solution that comes to my mind would be to create a static property in the App class to hold a reference to the ViewModel and in the OnResuming method call some ViewModel method which would handle the resuming.

Comment: That's one of the things I am having trouble with, getting a reference to the MainPageViewModel and in turn the IBandOperator so I can just call some sort of reset method. I can get access to the ModalDialog that template 10 using but can't find a reference to the ViewModel beyond that.

Comment: Just put this in your App class: public static TypeOfMyViewModel MyViewModel; In your TypeOfMyViewModel constructor, add this: App.MyViewModel = this; and then in the OnResuming method just call your method like this: MyViewModel.MyMethod(). I'll also update my answer so that you can see it more clearly.

Comment: That looks to have got it, thank you so much, was driving me mad... :D

Answer (score 1):

When you Suspend and Resume your app either through the Windows platform or through Visual Studio, the Resume operation is super-fast because it's just a memory swap. Your application does not generally even know your application was suspended in this case. AN example of this operation might be that your user gets a phone call and then returns to your app. With Template 10, your view-model INav methods are certainly not called because your app's state has not changed. If you must know it was suspended and is resuming, then you can tap into the OnResuming override in your app's Application/Bootstrapper. Depending on what you need to accomplish, you might need to expose this operation through a global static event so your view-models can handle it somehow.

In Visual Studio using Debug Location, you can then `Suspend and Shutdown` which will also suspend your app, but will change it's resume state from PreviousExecutionState=Running to Terminated. In this case, your app is certainly not still in memory and certainly not still in the same state. It is getting re-started, and Template 10 kicks in during this transition to restore your navigation state, settings, and everything else. It will also call your view-model's INav overrides like NavTo and NavFrom.

But beware. The Bootstrapper's OnResuming will also be called during this operation. Fortunately for you, the previous state is passed to this override and you can handle this unique case seamlessly in your calling code.

Make sense?

Best of luck.

Comment: Yea I think I mostly get how it works from extensive debugging and mapping the whole process out I was just having trouble actually implementing this part:  _If you must know it was suspended and is resuming, then you can tap into the OnResuming override in your app's Application/Bootstrapper. Depending on what you need to accomplish, you might need to expose this operation through a global static event so your view-models can handle it somehow._   Very green with anything but web development and this is my first real try at an app, windows 10 and band all at once so a lot to learn.. :D